# Drupal 7: parsing xml with Feeds extensible parsers

Tags: xml, xpath, drupal, drupal-feeds

Good day.

I have such an xml file:

```
<categories>
    <category id="1">Cat. 1</category>
    <category id="2">Cat. 2</category>
</categories>
```

All I need is to import category as term to my vocbulary. But I can't figure out how to do such thing.
My problem is that I cant configure importer properly. Next thing doesn't work, cuz title will be empty:

```
context: //categories/*
id: @id
title: category
```

If I go another way

```
context: /categories
title: category
id: category/@id
```

I will recieve two arrays: titles, id's. No taxonomy term will be added due to data type (array). So I can't split that array to get 1 (title,id) => 1 new term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is here
https://www.drupal.org/node/2542928#comment-10178930

context: /categories/category

title: text()

id: @id

Thanks to twistor from drupal.org

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Feeds Tamper](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_tamper) module, it gives you the ability to make changes to the data before Feeds imports it.

Comment: Already using it in another situations, but what plug-in should I use here? Split more than one array and insert each element as different record